# Using cookie in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, cookies, button

I have a like/dislike buttons and I put them in an update panel to be able to update the counter without refresh the page, the problem that the user can click like/dislike button several times and the counter will be changes

I want to allow user to click the button once I think I may use cookie but I didn't used it before so if anyone can help me doing that I will be thankful

also if there is any other solution that may be better please let me know

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use cookies, you can look at ***[this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vbtchaspnetcookies101anchor5)*** (older version) or ***[this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx)*** (newer version).

You haven't described what kind of website you are creating, but if you have a ***user registration/login mechanism***, you could just save information that a specific user clicked the *like* button in your database.

If logging in is not acceptable, you can try to identify your users by their IP addresses, as **Adam** suggested. You can do this by using:

```
String remoteAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

or

```
String remoteAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Either way I think it would be best to use cookies combined with another method, because you can then check the cookie first. If it exists on a user's computer, you know she/he has already voted. If the cookie is not there, you can query a database for the saved information about the user (identified by IP or login mechanism). This way you can make less queries to the database, which should be good for your application's performance :).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using cookies you can track via IP address.

I know IP addresses can change over time so you could use this with cookies but cookies can also be cleared so nothing will be 100%.

When a user clicks like or dislike, store their IP address with the record of the like.

Place code to stop another like or dislike counting if they already have done so.

Then on your update remove the like or dislike button and just show the count.

This is what I use for my application. I also have a Facebook app, in which I use their Facebook user Id which is much harder to fake.

Either way I think IP address is the best way to detect and stop someone from doing it twice.